# rails autoload not picking monkey-patched class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, monkeypatching

I'm working on a Rails 3 application (specifically 3.2.13) on ruby 1.9.3-p392.

In one of my controllers The "create" action can receive an image (as a ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)

I'm trying to monkeypatch ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile by overriding its as_json method to return the tempfile path instead of the tempfile File object itself.

The reason why I'm doing this is because I have a database logger that serializes the log context (which includes the request params) by calling to_json on the context.
Problem is that calling to_json on said class produces a ton of binary data which fill up my log.

So I have created the following directory structure under "lib":
"action_dispatch/http/uploaded_file.rb"
Inside this file the class is named `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`

I've also added the lib folder to application.rb by:
`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]`

Problem is that rails doesn't load my monkey-patched class.
If I add `require "action_dispatch/http/uploaded_file"`to the top of my controller file everything works fine.

Why doesn't Rails autoloads my monkey-patched class?
The directory structure and class naming is according to the Rails conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Move your code to `config/initializers/your_filename.rb` file. The code in these files is loaded during Rails Application boot process.

That's in general. But I'm not sure why you want to monkey-patch `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` class, because I haven't got much info about your app.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib"]
```